# Linux virtual user table email alias with multiple alias recipients

Tags: linux, email, alias, sendmail

I have a virtusertable file in /etc/mail/ with a list of email aliases and the email address, that should receive the mail when mail is sent to that alias, next to it.  The problem I have is when I want an alias to have two email addresses that receive mail from that address.

The below works:

TestAlias@example.com     RealEmailAddress@example.com

But the below does not work:

TestAlias@example.com     RealAddress1@example.com,RealAddress2@example.com

Comment: Which SMTP/MTA server do you use? sendmail/postfix/exim/...

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip I am using sendmail

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You may use "alias in the middle" approach/fix.
virtusertable -> alias -> final_list_of_recipients

virtusertable entry:

```
TestAlias@example.com  testalias-excom
```

aliases entry:

```
testalias-excom: RealAddress1@example.com,RealAddress2@example.com
```

---

Sendmail offers other ways to address the issue but I would not recommend them for "non advanced" postmasters.

Comment: in the file etc/mail/virtusertable add?:  

`TestAlias@example.com  testalias-excom `

And in the etc/mail/aliases add?:
`testalias-excom: RealAddress1@example.com,RealAddress2@example.com`